# how do i use html5 cache manifest in rails without rack-online

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have been searching all day for a way to use cache manifest in rails 3.1 but everything keeps pointing to rack-offline, which I don't want to use. How do I use this feature without rack-offline?

Thanks